# ASCII code for carriage return and line feed in C

Tags: c, arduino, arm, embedded

For ASCII code for carriage return and line feed, I used, 10 and 13 but they don't work properly. two characters after each word are printed like weird symbols. for example, like: `unsigned char ALERT[7]={'A','L','E','R','T',13,10}; 
Code is here: github.com/aliyah3/IoT/blob/master/Temperature_controller.c

Could anyone give me suggestion on fixing it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NNqP.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: have you tried `'\r'` and `'\n'`

Comment: Your string is "ALERT" but the display shows "TEMPERATURE" - it would be far better to post the code that relates to the result image.  Is the output means outputting exactly 7 characters or does it rely on nul termination - which you do not have?

Comment: Is this the data you send to the display directly? What kind of display is it? It may be that controlling cursor position (what you're trying to achieve with '\r' and '\n') isn't actually done by sending such character codes to it, but rather by sending totally separate commands, such as "set cursor position X, Y". If that is the case, the display may have some other characters in its character map under 0x0D and 0x0A, which would explain you seeing something you don't expect.

Comment: @Clifford Code is here: github.com/aliyah3/IoT/blob/master/Temperature_controller.c

Answer (score 2):

Try `unsigned char ALERT[]={'A','L','E','R','T','\r','\n','\0'};`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm sure. It seems like he wasn't null terminating the string, also it might not have been large enough

Comment: Yeah, that's another problem how it is used. I would do `ALERT[]="ALERT\n\r"`;

Comment: if \r and \n give you something other than 10 and 13 then something is broken they should be interchangeable, if not use 10 and 13...

Comment: If they're interchangeable, why obfuscate the meaning with numerical values?

Comment: It looks weird to me that this answer is downvoted but not the other one... (not that I call for downvoting the other one :) )

Comment: They are *not* interchangeable, and `\r` and `\n` are *not* guaranteed to be equivalent to 10 and 13.  Paragraph 5.2.2/3 of the standard says: "Each of these escape sequences shall produce a unique ***implementation-defined*** value which can be stored in a single char object. The external representations in a text file need not be identical to the internal representations, and are outside the scope of this International Standard" (emphasis added).  In practice, the source or execution character set (which are not guaranteed ASCII-compatible) might factor in.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Moreover, not only the runtime character set, but the control codes on the serial terminal that is probably used here since it is Arduino.

Comment: Its TM4C123G Microcontroller, I tried: unsigned char TEMP[]={'T','E','M','P','E','R','A','T','U','R','E','\r','\n','\0'}; 
unsigned char ALERT[]={'A','L','E','R','T','\r','\n','\0'}; 
 and just the first line is displayed. Just the "TEMPERATURE"

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried TEMP[]="TEMPERATURE/n/r"; ALERT[]="ALERT\n\r" but just the first line, "TEMPERATURE" was displayed.

Comment: @EugeneSh.   Everything is here: https://github.com/aliyah3/IoT/blob/master/Temperature_controller.c  thanks a bunch

Comment: It could be very well the case your LCD is not recognizing these characters. It is very likely since LCDs are often have special commands to move the cursor.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok, good point. I will look for characters for Nokia5110 LCD. Thank a lot. I really appreciate it. I will update this question if I find it.

Comment: Take a look at the sample code: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PCD8544 Looks like the subset of ascii from 0x20 to 0x7F is supported (with an offset of `0x20`, so your `10` will become `10-0x20` which is pretty bad).

Comment: The important lesson here is not to buy $2 LCD from China.:)

Comment: @AliyarAttaran Well, the LCD is fine. It is well documented as well. So that's a wrong lesson :) As I said, most of LCDs are working similarly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have never come across a system where "`\r` and `\n` are 10 and 13" _respectively_.  13 and 10, sure.  ;-)

Comment: Ah, @chux, but my point is that they *could* be 10 and 13, respectively :).  But for a more serious example, one might very well find `\n` to have the one of the values 21 or 37 (decimal) on a machine that is natively EBCDIC-based.

Comment: @AliyarAttaran : For an LCD module to translate ASCII control codes to cursor position would require it to have intelligence  - i.e. a microcontroller or some quite complex logic, making it unnecessarily expensive since your microcontroller already has that capability and code can send the necessary control signals or addressing.  You can set the line/column and it can use a look-up ROM to index glyph bitmaps with a character code and render them - what more would you need or expect?  It is a simple display, not a complete display termina.l

Comment: @JohnBollinger If code needs to use `10` for `'\n` to match the targets ASCII, then the letters in `{'A','L','E','R','T',...};` is likely problematic too.  Given that OP did not mention any letter issue, the code and the LCD are certainly using a consistent character encoding.  I suspect the control codes sent to the LCD are not interpreted by it as _control characters_.   IAC, OP's post is scant on needed information.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If the LCD is fine, it should recognize these special characters, right?